# Hyperledger Fabric Chaincode Deploment - DockerFile missing

Tags: dockerfile, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I would like to check if the following issue you have encountered while testing examples of `asset_management_with_roles`

Im running a 4 note Validator Node setup with 1 membersrvc in docker container setup. All setup steps have been followed but still this does not go.

Also I saw in code that a default docker image hyperledger/fabric-baseimage is needed for chaincode - that also I build from src but to no avail.

On deploying the chaincode the console at the "docker-compose up" shows the following message

CURL command to deploy:

```
curl -XPOST -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "deploy", "params": {"type": 1,"chaincodeID": { "name":"myam1","path": "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/asset_management_with_roles","language": "GOLANG"}, "ctorMsg": { "args": ["init"] }, "metadata":[97, 115, 115, 105, 103, 110, 101, 114] ,"secureContext": "assigner"} ,"id": 0}' http://192.168.99.100:7050/chaincode
```

----------- Error Message on Deploy --------------------

> vp2_1 | 07:50:51.447 [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 049 Error
>   building images: API error (500): {"message":"Cannot locate specified
>   Dockerfile: Dockerfile"}

Comment: Hello, I am facing the same problem trying to deploy java code directly with peer command. Did you get to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Pretty late reply but better late than never - The issue was related to different version of file at the container level. Instead of rebuilding from the SRC I downloaded the latest docker container images and all went fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the rest interface was discontinued in HyperLedger 1.0 so the above command will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to different version of file at the container level. Instead of rebuilding from the SRC I downloaded the latest docker container images and all went fine after that